# Asp.net MVC 5 only allow Integer

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to validate the text box only allow enter integer, decimal is not allow. I didnt manage to do it. I include these two jquery also didnt work.

> jquery.validate.js
>   jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js

Here is my code in model.

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Quantity is require")]
    [Display(Name = "Quantity")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:#}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Range(0, 9999, ErrorMessage = "Quantity must be POSITIVE (0-9999).")]
    public int QuantityStock { get; set; }
```

and view

```
                    <tr>
                        <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.QuantityStock)</td>
                        <td>:</td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.QuantityStock, new { @class="qtyCheck"}) <br />
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.QuantityStock)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

Appreciate your answer.

Comment: `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.QuantityStock, new { @class="qtyCheck",@type=''number"}) <br />` another way

Comment: What is JS version?, i had this issue before and solved it after upgrading it to current edition

Comment: @Just code hi it not work :(

Comment: @ShekharPankaj   it was 1.10.2

Comment: jQuery Validation (at least 1.11.1)
Microsoft jQuery Unobtrusive Validation (at least 2.0.30116.0)

Comment: Did you looked at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13984602/how-to-make-entry-field-to-allow-numbers-only-using-ef-and-data-annotations)?

Comment: @ShekharPankaj Is that any other option rather than upgrade the Jquery library, because i dunno how to change the Jquery Library..

Comment: @Mihail Stancescu i had tried the method mention in that post b4, it still not work..

Comment: @FirionRedfield dont upgrade it at first, use cdn and replace the existing script to check whether working or not.